# How to install PoshRSJob module offline?

Tags: powershell

I using [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) module in my powershell application.

How can I install this module to other machine (windows) without having internet connection (offline)?

Comment: Just download it and put it on the PS Module Folder, check it in this automatic variable: `$env:PSModulePath`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Save-Module` to save module to a local folder on a PC that has connection to internet and copy it to the PC without internet and put in into a `PSModulePath` directory

```
Save-Module PoshRSJob -Path %path%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend what @4c74356b41 said in that you can save the module with an internet connection using

```
Save-Module -Name PoshRSJob -Path C:\Temp\ -Force
```

But I'd recommend using `Install-Module` after you have it on the target PC as such:

```
$registerPSRepoArgs = @{
    InstallationPolicy        = 'Trusted'
    Name                      = 'tmp'
    PackageManagementProvider = 'NuGet'
    SourceLocation            = 'C:\Temp'
}
Register-PSRepository @registerPSRepoArgs
Install-Module -Name PoshRSJob -Force -Scope AllUsers -Repository tmp
Unregister-PSRepository -Name tmp
```

This will treat the package as if it came from the repository and handle any necessary setup so you don't have a bad configuration for whatever reason.  The `SourceLocation` is wherever you would drop the `PoshRSJob` folder you download using `Save-Module`.